# Taking 30yr average of a gridded (coordinate ordered), annual timeries dataset

Tags: r, time-series, coordinates, spatial

I have a .csv of a gridded dataset. Each grid (represented by lat/lon coordinates) has a annual timeseries from 1950-2100 and accompanyning values.

It's formated like this:

| time | lon | lat | value1 | value2 | value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1950-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1951-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 1952-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 3 | 6 | 9 |
| 1953-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 4 | 8 | 12 |
| 1954-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 5 | 10 | 15 |
| 1955-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1956-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 1957-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 3 | 6 | 9 |
| 1958-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 4 | 8 | 12 |
| 1959-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 5 | 10 | 15 |
| 1960-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| ..... | ..... | ..... | ..... | ..... | ..... |
| 1950-01-01 | -80.63 | 42.96 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1951-01-01 | -80.79 | 42.96 | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| ..... | ..... | ..... | ..... | ..... | ..... |
| 1950-01-01 | -79.88 | 44.29 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1951-01-01 | -79.88 | 44.26 | 2 | 4 | 6 |

You can get an real example of the .csv dataset at https://climatedata.ca/download/ (pick frequency: annual; variable: anyone; location: pick 2+ grids on the map)

**I"m trying to figure out how to take 30 year averages for each grid.**

For example, for for the first grid (-80.79, 42.96) I want to take the averages from 1950-1969, 1970-2005, 2006-2039, 2049-2069, and 2070-2100. Then do the same thing for the second grid. Etc.

Or,

Take the average from 1950-1969 for each grid, then take the average for 1970-2005 for each grid. Etc.

**Basically I want to be able to repeat the same calcualtions for one grid onto all of them.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option, where we can use `case_when` to create the groups, then `summarise`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(time = format(as.Date(time), "%Y")) %>%
  group_by(lon, lat,
         grp = case_when(time >= 1950 & time <= 1969 ~ "1950-1969",
                           time >= 1970 & time <= 2005 ~ "1970-2005",
                           time >= 2006 & time <= 2039 ~ "2006-2039",
                           time >= 2040 & time <= 2069 ~ "2040-2069",
                           time >= 2070 & time <= 2100 ~ "2070-2100",
                           TRUE ~ NA_character_)) %>%
  summarise(across(-time, ~ mean(.x, na.rm = T)))
```

**Output**

```
     lon   lat   grp       rcp26_tg_mean_p10 rcp26_tg_mean_p… rcp26_tg_mean_p… rcp45_tg_mean_p… rcp45_tg_mean_p… rcp45_tg_mean_p… rcp85_tg_mean_p… rcp85_tg_mean_p… rcp85_tg_mean_p…
   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 -112.88 49.7 1950-1969              3.98             5.43             6.80             3.98             5.43             6.80             3.98             5.42             6.79
 2 -112.88 49.7 1970-2005              4.38             5.77             7.11             4.38             5.77             7.12             4.39             5.76             7.11
 3 -112.88 49.7 2006-2039              5.62             7.10             8.58             5.64             7.09             8.53             5.67             7.28             8.67
 4 -112.88 49.7 2040-2069              6.05             7.69             9.36             6.79             8.31             9.98             7.48             9.08            10.8 
 5 -112.88 49.7 2070-2100              6.28             7.73             9.38             7.36             9.06            10.8              9.36            11.3             13.1 
 6 -112.79 49.7 1950-1969              3.88             5.34             6.71             3.88             5.34             6.71             3.88             5.33             6.71
 7 -112.79 49.7 1970-2005              4.28             5.67             7.03             4.28             5.67             7.03             4.28             5.66             7.02
 8 -112.79 49.7 2006-2039              5.52             7.01             8.49             5.54             7.00             8.44             5.57             7.19             8.58
 9 -112.79 49.7 2040-2069              5.95             7.60             9.27             6.69             8.22             9.90             7.38             8.98            10.8 
10 -112.79 49.7 2070-2100              5.97             7.66             9.06             7.37             8.93            10.6              8.63            10.3             12.1
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(time = c("1950-01-01", "1951-01-01", "1952-01-01", 
"1953-01-01", "1954-01-01", "1955-01-01", "1956-01-01", "1957-01-01", 
"1958-01-01", "1959-01-01", "1960-01-01", "1961-01-01", "1962-01-01", 
"1963-01-01", "1964-01-01", "1965-01-01", "1966-01-01", "1967-01-01", 
"1968-01-01", "1969-01-01", "1970-01-01", "1971-01-01", "1972-01-01", 
"1973-01-01", "1974-01-01", "1975-01-01", "1976-01-01", "1977-01-01", 
"1978-01-01", "1979-01-01", "1980-01-01", "1981-01-01", "1982-01-01", 
"1983-01-01", "1984-01-01", "1985-01-01", "1986-01-01", "1987-01-01", 
"1988-01-01", "1989-01-01", "1990-01-01", "1991-01-01", "1992-01-01", 
"1993-01-01", "1994-01-01", "1995-01-01", "1996-01-01", "1997-01-01", 
"1998-01-01", "1999-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2002-01-01", 
"2003-01-01", "2004-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2006-01-01", "2007-01-01", 
"2008-01-01", "2009-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", 
"2013-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", 
"2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2022-01-01", 
"2023-01-01", "2024-01-01", "2025-01-01", "2026-01-01", "2027-01-01", 
"2028-01-01", "2029-01-01", "2030-01-01", "2031-01-01", "2032-01-01", 
"2033-01-01", "2034-01-01", "2035-01-01", "2036-01-01", "2037-01-01", 
"2038-01-01", "2039-01-01", "2040-01-01", "2041-01-01", "2042-01-01", 
"2043-01-01", "2044-01-01", "2045-01-01", "2046-01-01", "2047-01-01", 
"2048-01-01", "2049-01-01", "2050-01-01", "2051-01-01", "2052-01-01", 
"2053-01-01", "2054-01-01", "2055-01-01", "2056-01-01", "2057-01-01", 
"2058-01-01", "2059-01-01", "2060-01-01", "2061-01-01", "2062-01-01", 
"2063-01-01", "2064-01-01", "2065-01-01", "2066-01-01", "2067-01-01", 
"2068-01-01", "2069-01-01", "2070-01-01", "2071-01-01", "2072-01-01", 
"2073-01-01", "2074-01-01", "2075-01-01", "2076-01-01", "2077-01-01", 
"2078-01-01", "2079-01-01", "2080-01-01", "2081-01-01", "2082-01-01", 
"2083-01-01", "2084-01-01", "2085-01-01", "2086-01-01", "2087-01-01", 
"2088-01-01", "2089-01-01", "2090-01-01", "2091-01-01", "2092-01-01", 
"2093-01-01", "2094-01-01", "2095-01-01", "2096-01-01", "2097-01-01", 
"2098-01-01", "2099-01-01", "2100-01-01", "1950-01-01", "1951-01-01", 
"1952-01-01", "1953-01-01", "1954-01-01", "1955-01-01", "1956-01-01", 
"1957-01-01", "1958-01-01", "1959-01-01", "1960-01-01", "1961-01-01", 
"1962-01-01", "1963-01-01", "1964-01-01", "1965-01-01", "1966-01-01", 
"1967-01-01", "1968-01-01", "1969-01-01", "1970-01-01", "1971-01-01", 
"1972-01-01", "1973-01-01", "1974-01-01", "1975-01-01", "1976-01-01", 
"1977-01-01", "1978-01-01", "1979-01-01", "1980-01-01", "1981-01-01", 
"1982-01-01", "1983-01-01", "1984-01-01", "1985-01-01", "1986-01-01", 
"1987-01-01", "1988-01-01", "1989-01-01", "1990-01-01", "1991-01-01", 
"1992-01-01", "1993-01-01", "1994-01-01", "1995-01-01", "1996-01-01", 
"1997-01-01", "1998-01-01", "1999-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2001-01-01", 
"2002-01-01", "2003-01-01", "2004-01-01", "2005-01-01", "2006-01-01", 
"2007-01-01", "2008-01-01", "2009-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2011-01-01", 
"2012-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01", 
"2017-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", 
"2022-01-01", "2023-01-01", "2024-01-01", "2025-01-01", "2026-01-01", 
"2027-01-01", "2028-01-01", "2029-01-01", "2030-01-01", "2031-01-01", 
"2032-01-01", "2033-01-01", "2034-01-01", "2035-01-01", "2036-01-01", 
"2037-01-01", "2038-01-01", "2039-01-01", "2040-01-01", "2041-01-01", 
"2042-01-01", "2043-01-01", "2044-01-01", "2045-01-01", "2046-01-01", 
"2047-01-01", "2048-01-01", "2049-01-01", "2050-01-01", "2051-01-01", 
"2052-01-01", "2053-01-01", "2054-01-01", "2055-01-01", "2056-01-01", 
"2057-01-01", "2058-01-01", "2059-01-01", "2060-01-01", "2061-01-01", 
"2062-01-01", "2063-01-01", "2064-01-01", "2065-01-01", "2066-01-01", 
"2067-01-01", "2068-01-01", "2069-01-01", "2070-01-01", "2071-01-01", 
"2072-01-01", "2073-01-01", "2074-01-01", "2075-01-01", "2076-01-01", 
"2077-01-01", "2078-01-01"), lat = c(49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 
49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71, 49.71), lon = c(-112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, -112.88, 
-112.88, -112.88, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, 
-112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79, -112.79), rcp26_tg_mean_p10 = c(4.8, 
4.62, 4.23, 4.16, 4.63, 4.1, 4.52, 3.43, 3.7, 3.32, 3.66, 4.16, 
3.78, 4.57, 3.34, 3.59, 3.75, 4.46, 3.1, 3.74, 3.87, 4.37, 4.07, 
4.25, 3.52, 4.52, 4.44, 4.41, 5.22, 4.19, 4.18, 3.54, 3.63, 4.11, 
4.44, 3.77, 4.98, 4.26, 4.06, 4.96, 4.04, 4.1, 3.99, 4.36, 4.44, 
3.85, 4.41, 4.23, 4.93, 5.21, 5.29, 4.82, 4.68, 4.82, 5.13, 4.68, 
4.83, 5.19, 5.82, 5.58, 4.28, 4.94, 5.66, 5.32, 4.92, 5.73, 5.94, 
5.16, 4.83, 5.84, 5.81, 5.77, 5.21, 5.53, 6.1, 5.1, 6.45, 5.28, 
6.19, 5.91, 6.47, 5.86, 5.7, 6.02, 6.06, 5.85, 6.06, 6.17, 5.64, 
5.78, 6.12, 5.24, 5.92, 6.26, 4.91, 6.3, 6.34, 5.53, 6.26, 6.01, 
6.29, 5.92, 6.04, 5.39, 6.43, 6.52, 6.3, 5.73, 6.05, 5.89, 6.61, 
6.5, 6.21, 5.5, 5.39, 5.83, 6.54, 6.56, 6.39, 6.43, 6.1, 6.48, 
5.57, 6.3, 7.05, 6.23, 6.38, 5.67, 4.75, 6.12, 6.27, 6.47, 6.66, 
6.12, 6.16, 6.75, 6.4, 6.18, 6.85, 6.66, 6.12, 6.51, 6.07, 6.48, 
6.03, 6.17, 6.31, 6.53, 6.19, 6.5, 6.61, 4.7, 4.51, 4.14, 4.05, 
4.54, 4, 4.44, 3.32, 3.58, 3.22, 3.56, 4.07, 3.67, 4.47, 3.24, 
3.48, 3.64, 4.36, 2.99, 3.64, 3.75, 4.27, 3.97, 4.16, 3.42, 4.39, 
4.33, 4.31, 5.11, 4.08, 4.07, 3.42, 3.51, 4, 4.34, 3.66, 4.88, 
4.16, 3.96, 4.85, 3.96, 4.02, 3.89, 4.26, 4.34, 3.75, 4.31, 4.11, 
4.83, 5.12, 5.19, 4.72, 4.58, 4.72, 5, 4.57, 4.73, 5.11, 5.72, 
5.48, 4.17, 4.85, 5.55, 5.21, 4.82, 5.63, 5.83, 5.06, 4.74, 5.76, 
5.71, 5.67, 5.1, 5.43, 5.97, 5, 6.33, 5.17, 6.09, 5.81, 6.38, 
5.75, 5.58, 5.92, 5.95, 5.75, 5.98, 6.08, 5.54, 5.68, 6.01, 5.14, 
5.82, 6.16, 4.81, 6.21, 6.23, 5.42, 6.18, 5.93, 6.2, 5.8, 5.95, 
5.3, 6.36, 6.43, 6.18, 5.61, 5.97, 5.79, 6.51, 6.4, 6.11, 5.39, 
5.28, 5.72, 6.45, 6.45, 6.28, 6.33, 6, 6.38, 5.49, 6.22, 6.96, 
6.14, 6.28, 5.57, 4.65), rcp26_tg_mean_p50 = c(6.02, 5.96, 5.44, 
5.65, 5.45, 5.52, 5.44, 5.37, 5.24, 5.21, 5.26, 5.75, 5.63, 5.59, 
4.64, 5.19, 5.06, 5.59, 5.36, 5.15, 5.53, 5.69, 5.37, 5.23, 5.42, 
5.34, 5.77, 5.69, 5.81, 6.03, 5.24, 5.83, 5.62, 5.1, 6.04, 5.24, 
5.79, 5.74, 5.68, 5.82, 5.87, 5.7, 5.05, 5.66, 5.88, 5.38, 5.75, 
5.84, 6.12, 6.25, 6.42, 6.05, 6.85, 6.15, 6.28, 6.34, 6.6, 6.05, 
6.83, 6.94, 6.45, 6.29, 6.98, 6.64, 7.14, 6.89, 7.19, 6.89, 7.21, 
6.66, 6.92, 7.13, 6.76, 7.27, 7.73, 7.03, 7.16, 7.4, 7.2, 7.29, 
7.5, 7.15, 7.46, 7.14, 7.74, 7.83, 7.56, 7.33, 7.83, 7.32, 7.39, 
6.86, 7.19, 7.43, 7.48, 8.01, 7.86, 7.3, 7.43, 7.63, 7.97, 8.05, 
7.54, 7.33, 8.24, 8.32, 8.33, 8.13, 7.63, 7.76, 7.88, 7.81, 7.39, 
7.8, 7.93, 7.76, 7.51, 7.49, 7.54, 7.79, 7.68, 7.75, 7.14, 8.08, 
7.87, 7.72, 7.97, 7.78, 7.79, 7.63, 7.71, 7.82, 7.65, 7.93, 7.67, 
7.79, 8.02, 7.28, 8.29, 8.23, 7.29, 7.67, 7.83, 7.38, 7.41, 7.75, 
7.4, 7.8, 7.3, 7.9, 8.08, 5.94, 5.87, 5.39, 5.55, 5.37, 5.42, 
5.34, 5.27, 5.16, 5.12, 5.17, 5.66, 5.54, 5.5, 4.54, 5.1, 4.97, 
5.5, 5.26, 5.05, 5.43, 5.6, 5.27, 5.14, 5.32, 5.24, 5.67, 5.6, 
5.72, 5.94, 5.15, 5.73, 5.54, 5.01, 5.95, 5.14, 5.67, 5.65, 5.59, 
5.72, 5.77, 5.61, 4.94, 5.55, 5.79, 5.31, 5.66, 5.73, 6.02, 6.17, 
6.34, 5.95, 6.72, 6.06, 6.18, 6.23, 6.49, 5.96, 6.75, 6.83, 6.35, 
6.21, 6.89, 6.55, 7.05, 6.79, 7.11, 6.79, 7.1, 6.54, 6.83, 7.08, 
6.67, 7.19, 7.66, 6.93, 7.06, 7.31, 7.11, 7.19, 7.41, 7.05, 7.37, 
7.03, 7.65, 7.74, 7.47, 7.25, 7.73, 7.23, 7.29, 6.76, 7.1, 7.32, 
7.37, 7.92, 7.76, 7.21, 7.34, 7.54, 7.88, 7.96, 7.44, 7.23, 8.16, 
8.21, 8.26, 8.04, 7.54, 7.64, 7.79, 7.71, 7.29, 7.71, 7.84, 7.66, 
7.42, 7.4, 7.45, 7.7, 7.6, 7.66, 7.04, 8, 7.78, 7.62, 7.87, 7.69, 
7.7), rcp26_tg_mean_p90 = c(7.35, 7.39, 6.72, 6.63, 6.87, 6.74, 
6.86, 7.1, 6.51, 6.28, 7.08, 7.07, 7.02, 7.43, 5.95, 5.8, 6.8, 
6.82, 6.73, 6.81, 6.86, 7.04, 5.92, 7.09, 6.64, 6.24, 7.02, 7.06, 
6.81, 7.74, 6.95, 6.95, 6.52, 6.35, 6.81, 6.77, 7.44, 6.7, 6.72, 
7.07, 6.7, 7.6, 7.55, 7.19, 7.17, 7.5, 6.69, 7.75, 7.38, 7.12, 
7.74, 7.14, 7.81, 8.08, 7.91, 8.1, 7.61, 8.19, 7.58, 8.22, 8.09, 
7.89, 8.37, 8.11, 8.27, 7.89, 9, 8.42, 8.23, 7.9, 8.59, 8.38, 
9.35, 8.18, 8.88, 8.26, 8.14, 9.29, 8.92, 8.95, 8.59, 9.43, 8.89, 
9.25, 9.14, 8.98, 9.52, 8.8, 8.5, 9.82, 9.35, 9.08, 9.47, 8.39, 
9.24, 9.3, 9.44, 9.55, 9.41, 8.53, 9.06, 9.58, 9.39, 8.99, 9.78, 
10, 9.67, 9.74, 9.48, 10.07, 9.96, 9.43, 10.15, 8.77, 9.45, 9.17, 
8.86, 9.11, 9.27, 9.1, 9.33, 9.07, 8.82, 9.61, 9.03, 9.71, 9.52, 
8.75, 8.58, 8.87, 9.42, 9.24, 9.16, 9.63, 9.27, 9.86, 9.4, 10, 
10.19, 9.81, 9.41, 9.09, 9.66, 9.49, 8.63, 10.09, 9.37, 9.69, 
8.59, 9.83, 9.63, 7.26, 7.3, 6.65, 6.54, 6.78, 6.66, 6.77, 7.01, 
6.43, 6.19, 6.99, 6.97, 6.93, 7.34, 5.85, 5.71, 6.73, 6.75, 6.67, 
6.73, 6.77, 6.98, 5.83, 7.02, 6.55, 6.14, 6.93, 6.98, 6.72, 7.66, 
6.86, 6.86, 6.42, 6.25, 6.73, 6.68, 7.35, 6.61, 6.63, 6.97, 6.61, 
7.54, 7.46, 7.12, 7.08, 7.42, 6.6, 7.65, 7.31, 7.02, 7.66, 7.05, 
7.72, 7.99, 7.84, 8.01, 7.52, 8.1, 7.5, 8.12, 7.99, 7.79, 8.28, 
8.04, 8.18, 7.81, 8.92, 8.34, 8.12, 7.8, 8.52, 8.27, 9.24, 8.09, 
8.8, 8.18, 8.06, 9.21, 8.81, 8.85, 8.5, 9.35, 8.81, 9.17, 9.06, 
8.9, 9.44, 8.72, 8.4, 9.75, 9.25, 8.98, 9.39, 8.3, 9.16, 9.21, 
9.34, 9.46, 9.32, 8.43, 8.98, 9.5, 9.3, 8.92, 9.69, 9.92, 9.58, 
9.66, 9.38, 10, 9.89, 9.35, 10.07, 8.67, 9.38, 9.08, 8.77, 9.01, 
9.19, 9.01, 9.23, 8.98, 8.72, 9.52, 8.93, 9.62, 9.43, 8.66, 8.49
), rcp45_tg_mean_p10 = c(4.8, 4.62, 4.23, 4.16, 4.63, 4.1, 4.52, 
3.43, 3.7, 3.32, 3.66, 4.16, 3.78, 4.57, 3.34, 3.59, 3.75, 4.46, 
3.1, 3.74, 3.87, 4.37, 4.07, 4.25, 3.52, 4.52, 4.44, 4.41, 5.22, 
4.19, 4.17, 3.52, 3.63, 4.09, 4.47, 3.76, 5.01, 4.29, 4.07, 5.01, 
4.05, 4.1, 3.99, 4.35, 4.43, 3.85, 4.44, 4.23, 4.95, 5.26, 5.3, 
4.81, 4.65, 4.83, 5.14, 4.59, 5.57, 5.25, 4.6, 5.58, 5.4, 5.51, 
5.4, 4.88, 5.07, 4.73, 4.85, 5.67, 4.9, 5.73, 5, 5.57, 5.4, 5.21, 
6.46, 5.58, 5.86, 5.75, 5.59, 5.62, 6.38, 5.77, 5.55, 6.32, 6.71, 
5.91, 5.76, 6.99, 6.93, 6.2, 6.41, 6.17, 6.79, 6.13, 6.09, 6.45, 
6.7, 7.19, 6.04, 6.26, 6.82, 6.73, 7.33, 6.92, 6.59, 6.6, 6.65, 
6.76, 7.47, 6.78, 7.05, 6.81, 7.27, 6.44, 7.8, 6.9, 7.84, 7.35, 
7.01, 6.26, 7.1, 7.76, 7.07, 7.53, 7.04, 7.37, 7.82, 7.84, 7.7, 
6.86, 7.81, 6.87, 7.87, 7.19, 7.09, 6.34, 7.37, 7.07, 6.9, 6.76, 
7.64, 7.66, 7.37, 7.82, 7.01, 7.53, 8.04, 6.87, 7.89, 7.79, 7.11, 
4.7, 4.51, 4.14, 4.05, 4.54, 4, 4.44, 3.32, 3.58, 3.22, 3.56, 
4.07, 3.67, 4.47, 3.24, 3.48, 3.64, 4.36, 2.99, 3.64, 3.75, 4.27, 
3.97, 4.16, 3.42, 4.39, 4.33, 4.31, 5.11, 4.08, 4.07, 3.4, 3.51, 
3.98, 4.35, 3.65, 4.91, 4.19, 3.97, 4.89, 3.97, 4.02, 3.88, 4.24, 
4.34, 3.75, 4.34, 4.11, 4.85, 5.17, 5.21, 4.71, 4.55, 4.73, 5, 
4.49, 5.47, 5.15, 4.51, 5.48, 5.3, 5.4, 5.3, 4.77, 4.97, 4.61, 
4.74, 5.57, 4.79, 5.63, 4.89, 5.48, 5.3, 5.12, 6.37, 5.47, 5.76, 
5.65, 5.49, 5.52, 6.29, 5.66, 5.44, 6.23, 6.58, 5.82, 5.66, 6.89, 
6.82, 6.09, 6.3, 6.09, 6.69, 6.03, 5.99, 6.34, 6.61, 7.08, 5.95, 
6.16, 6.7, 6.64, 7.22, 6.84, 6.5, 6.5, 6.57, 6.67, 7.37, 6.71, 
6.96, 6.71, 7.17, 6.34, 7.71, 6.79, 7.74, 7.26, 6.93, 6.15, 6.99, 
7.69, 6.97, 7.43, 6.94, 7.28, 7.72, 7.75, 7.6), rcp45_tg_mean_p50 = c(6.02, 
5.96, 5.44, 5.65, 5.45, 5.52, 5.44, 5.37, 5.24, 5.21, 5.26, 5.75, 
5.63, 5.59, 4.64, 5.19, 5.06, 5.59, 5.36, 5.15, 5.53, 5.69, 5.37, 
5.23, 5.42, 5.34, 5.77, 5.69, 5.81, 6.03, 5.26, 5.82, 5.62, 5.1, 
6.04, 5.25, 5.77, 5.75, 5.68, 5.81, 5.86, 5.69, 5.07, 5.64, 5.89, 
5.4, 5.75, 5.85, 6.16, 6.26, 6.42, 6.04, 6.85, 6.2, 6.27, 6.32, 
6.95, 6.48, 6.54, 6.82, 6.39, 6.74, 6.25, 6.42, 6.26, 6.8, 6.38, 
6.94, 6.98, 6.77, 6.79, 6.92, 6.83, 7.64, 7.64, 7.21, 7.64, 7.54, 
7.69, 6.76, 7.1, 7.1, 7.69, 7.62, 7.84, 7.7, 7.27, 8.22, 7.78, 
7.49, 7.31, 7.8, 7.78, 7.98, 7.98, 8.16, 8.26, 8.36, 7.72, 8.09, 
7.71, 8.04, 8.43, 8.81, 8.72, 8.87, 8.04, 8.16, 9.09, 8.41, 7.86, 
8.09, 9.02, 8.5, 8.77, 8.84, 9.01, 8.78, 8.33, 8.5, 8.86, 9.36, 
9.64, 8.85, 8.5, 8.9, 9.13, 9, 8.95, 9.36, 8.4, 8.85, 8.83, 8.7, 
9.16, 9.02, 8.62, 8.6, 8.65, 9.2, 9.21, 9.22, 9.68, 9.13, 8.93, 
9.44, 9.3, 9.2, 9.31, 9.85, 8.88, 5.94, 5.87, 5.39, 5.55, 5.37, 
5.42, 5.34, 5.27, 5.16, 5.12, 5.17, 5.66, 5.54, 5.5, 4.54, 5.1, 
4.97, 5.5, 5.26, 5.05, 5.43, 5.6, 5.27, 5.14, 5.32, 5.24, 5.67, 
5.6, 5.72, 5.94, 5.16, 5.72, 5.53, 5.01, 5.94, 5.14, 5.66, 5.65, 
5.59, 5.7, 5.76, 5.59, 4.96, 5.53, 5.8, 5.33, 5.66, 5.75, 6.07, 
6.18, 6.33, 5.94, 6.74, 6.11, 6.17, 6.22, 6.86, 6.38, 6.42, 6.72, 
6.29, 6.66, 6.15, 6.32, 6.18, 6.71, 6.28, 6.82, 6.89, 6.68, 6.69, 
6.84, 6.71, 7.55, 7.55, 7.13, 7.53, 7.43, 7.6, 6.65, 6.99, 7, 
7.6, 7.54, 7.74, 7.6, 7.17, 8.12, 7.7, 7.4, 7.21, 7.7, 7.68, 
7.87, 7.89, 8.07, 8.16, 8.26, 7.64, 8, 7.61, 7.95, 8.33, 8.72, 
8.64, 8.78, 7.95, 8.06, 9.02, 8.32, 7.75, 7.99, 8.91, 8.4, 8.67, 
8.74, 8.92, 8.7, 8.23, 8.39, 8.74, 9.27, 9.56, 8.78, 8.4, 8.82, 
9.04, 8.9, 8.85), rcp45_tg_mean_p90 = c(7.35, 7.39, 6.72, 6.63, 
6.87, 6.74, 6.86, 7.1, 6.51, 6.28, 7.08, 7.07, 7.02, 7.43, 5.95, 
5.8, 6.8, 6.82, 6.73, 6.81, 6.86, 7.04, 5.92, 7.09, 6.64, 6.24, 
7.02, 7.06, 6.81, 7.74, 6.94, 6.97, 6.51, 6.35, 6.8, 6.79, 7.4, 
6.74, 6.71, 7.07, 6.71, 7.59, 7.55, 7.22, 7.16, 7.51, 6.69, 7.75, 
7.4, 7.13, 7.76, 7.14, 7.8, 8.08, 7.91, 8.11, 8.53, 7.63, 7.81, 
8.18, 7.77, 8.09, 7.51, 7.42, 8.03, 7.71, 7.76, 8.36, 8.53, 8.54, 
8.63, 8.3, 7.57, 8.8, 8.78, 8.93, 9.73, 8.53, 9.21, 8.68, 8.63, 
8.81, 9.53, 9.02, 8.77, 9.24, 9.04, 9.93, 8.99, 9.02, 8.82, 9.1, 
9.07, 9.71, 9.62, 9.95, 9.99, 9.69, 9.59, 9.96, 9.68, 9.85, 10.12, 
10.02, 9.86, 10.16, 9.62, 10, 10.75, 10.21, 10.1, 10.13, 10.21, 
10.99, 10.63, 10.49, 10.75, 9.92, 10.26, 10.29, 10.43, 10.78, 
10.89, 10.79, 11.21, 10.64, 10.15, 10.36, 10.83, 11.08, 10.78, 
11.31, 10.72, 10.73, 10.81, 10.6, 10.97, 11.06, 10.34, 10.85, 
11.31, 10.62, 11.02, 10.18, 10.62, 10.72, 10.56, 11.37, 10.68, 
11.38, 10.93, 7.26, 7.3, 6.65, 6.54, 6.78, 6.66, 6.77, 7.01, 
6.43, 6.19, 6.99, 6.97, 6.93, 7.34, 5.85, 5.71, 6.73, 6.75, 6.67, 
6.73, 6.77, 6.98, 5.83, 7.02, 6.55, 6.14, 6.93, 6.98, 6.72, 7.66, 
6.85, 6.88, 6.41, 6.25, 6.72, 6.7, 7.31, 6.65, 6.62, 6.97, 6.62, 
7.52, 7.46, 7.15, 7.08, 7.43, 6.59, 7.65, 7.32, 7.04, 7.68, 7.04, 
7.72, 7.99, 7.83, 8.02, 8.45, 7.53, 7.73, 8.09, 7.68, 8, 7.41, 
7.33, 7.92, 7.62, 7.68, 8.28, 8.45, 8.45, 8.54, 8.22, 7.48, 8.72, 
8.69, 8.87, 9.64, 8.42, 9.12, 8.6, 8.55, 8.72, 9.43, 8.94, 8.66, 
9.14, 8.97, 9.84, 8.9, 8.93, 8.72, 9.05, 8.97, 9.62, 9.52, 9.86, 
9.9, 9.6, 9.49, 9.86, 9.6, 9.76, 10.04, 9.93, 9.77, 10.07, 9.53, 
9.92, 10.67, 10.13, 9.99, 10.04, 10.12, 10.92, 10.54, 10.4, 10.66, 
9.81, 10.18, 10.2, 10.34, 10.69, 10.8, 10.73, 11.12, 10.56, 10.07, 
10.27, 10.73), rcp85_tg_mean_p10 = c(4.8, 4.62, 4.23, 4.16, 4.63, 
4.1, 4.52, 3.43, 3.7, 3.32, 3.66, 4.16, 3.78, 4.57, 3.34, 3.59, 
3.75, 4.46, 3.1, 3.74, 3.87, 4.37, 4.07, 4.25, 3.52, 4.52, 4.44, 
4.41, 5.22, 4.19, 4.17, 3.52, 3.64, 4.08, 4.46, 3.76, 5, 4.28, 
4.06, 5.02, 3.98, 4.03, 3.99, 4.35, 4.43, 3.85, 4.45, 4.21, 4.93, 
5.27, 5.3, 4.8, 4.65, 4.83, 5.15, 4.92, 5.74, 5.29, 5.02, 5.03, 
4.22, 5.25, 5.06, 4.81, 5.13, 4.66, 5.65, 5.45, 5.28, 4.8, 5.93, 
4.99, 5.66, 6.49, 5.85, 6.06, 5.96, 5.66, 6.45, 6.55, 5.84, 5.98, 
5.86, 5.96, 5.67, 6.98, 5.69, 6.81, 6.68, 6.44, 6.01, 6.63, 6.85, 
6.49, 6.32, 6.69, 7.09, 7.06, 6.88, 7.08, 6.48, 7.13, 6.67, 8.08, 
7.87, 7.55, 8.06, 7.47, 7.94, 8.4, 7.61, 7.26, 8.11, 7.85, 8.15, 
8.13, 8.24, 8.01, 8.76, 9.52, 8.25, 8.22, 8.17, 8.57, 8.64, 9.6, 
9.13, 9.14, 8.84, 8.98, 8.91, 9.41, 9.99, 8.65, 8.97, 8.58, 9.66, 
10.01, 9.14, 9.41, 10.12, 10.18, 10.06, 9.73, 9.2, 9.25, 9.4, 
10.84, 10.14, 9.97, 11.09, 4.7, 4.51, 4.14, 4.05, 4.54, 4, 4.44, 
3.32, 3.58, 3.22, 3.56, 4.07, 3.67, 4.47, 3.24, 3.48, 3.64, 4.36, 
2.99, 3.64, 3.75, 4.27, 3.97, 4.16, 3.42, 4.39, 4.33, 4.31, 5.11, 
4.08, 4.07, 3.4, 3.52, 3.97, 4.35, 3.65, 4.9, 4.18, 3.96, 4.9, 
3.88, 3.93, 3.89, 4.24, 4.34, 3.75, 4.35, 4.1, 4.83, 5.19, 5.21, 
4.7, 4.55, 4.73, 5.01, 4.81, 5.63, 5.2, 4.92, 4.94, 4.09, 5.15, 
4.95, 4.71, 5.03, 4.56, 5.54, 5.35, 5.18, 4.66, 5.84, 4.89, 5.56, 
6.38, 5.74, 5.96, 5.84, 5.53, 6.32, 6.44, 5.73, 5.87, 5.77, 5.84, 
5.57, 6.88, 5.6, 6.71, 6.59, 6.31, 5.9, 6.52, 6.76, 6.4, 6.21, 
6.56, 6.98, 6.91, 6.78, 6.99, 6.39, 7.03, 6.57, 7.99, 7.78, 7.45, 
7.97, 7.37, 7.84, 8.3, 7.51, 7.16, 8.01, 7.75, 8.06, 8.05, 8.14, 
7.9, 8.68, 9.43, 8.14, 8.12, 8.08, 8.47, 8.54, 9.49, 9.02, 9.04, 
8.74), rcp85_tg_mean_p50 = c(6.02, 5.95, 5.44, 5.65, 5.42, 5.52, 
5.44, 5.37, 5.22, 5.21, 5.26, 5.75, 5.6, 5.55, 4.64, 5.19, 5.06, 
5.59, 5.36, 5.15, 5.53, 5.69, 5.37, 5.23, 5.42, 5.34, 5.77, 5.69, 
5.81, 6.03, 5.25, 5.82, 5.61, 5.09, 6.03, 5.24, 5.77, 5.75, 5.68, 
5.81, 5.86, 5.7, 5.03, 5.66, 5.86, 5.35, 5.75, 5.85, 6.14, 6.21, 
6.39, 6.03, 6.85, 6.21, 6.26, 6.33, 6.93, 6.95, 6.56, 6.69, 6.33, 
6.13, 6.36, 6.65, 6.6, 6.59, 6.9, 7.16, 7.32, 7.37, 6.98, 6.89, 
7.72, 7.33, 7.07, 7.2, 7.11, 7.31, 7.95, 7.83, 7.51, 7.3, 7.38, 
7.74, 8.36, 8.52, 7.69, 8.26, 8.43, 8.41, 7.89, 7.88, 7.72, 8.61, 
7.46, 8.23, 8.22, 8.54, 8.82, 8.92, 8.39, 8.71, 8.47, 9.21, 9.03, 
9.12, 9.31, 9.05, 9.38, 9.73, 9.05, 8.87, 9.7, 9.71, 10.05, 9.98, 
10.23, 10.28, 10.66, 11.07, 10.19, 10.03, 10.32, 10.31, 10.24, 
10.33, 10.6, 10.72, 10.76, 10.75, 10.89, 10.71, 11.9, 11.36, 
11.14, 11.39, 11.24, 11.54, 11.11, 11.93, 11.3, 12.24, 11.81, 
11.96, 11.9, 11.29, 12.12, 12.59, 12.73, 12.21, 12.84, 5.94, 
5.86, 5.39, 5.55, 5.33, 5.42, 5.34, 5.27, 5.11, 5.12, 5.17, 5.66, 
5.51, 5.45, 4.54, 5.1, 4.97, 5.5, 5.26, 5.05, 5.43, 5.6, 5.27, 
5.14, 5.32, 5.24, 5.67, 5.6, 5.72, 5.94, 5.16, 5.72, 5.53, 4.99, 
5.94, 5.14, 5.66, 5.65, 5.59, 5.7, 5.76, 5.61, 4.92, 5.55, 5.77, 
5.26, 5.65, 5.74, 6.04, 6.12, 6.3, 5.93, 6.73, 6.12, 6.16, 6.23, 
6.84, 6.85, 6.48, 6.59, 6.24, 6.04, 6.27, 6.55, 6.51, 6.5, 6.8, 
7.07, 7.23, 7.27, 6.89, 6.79, 7.62, 7.21, 6.97, 7.11, 7.02, 7.23, 
7.86, 7.75, 7.42, 7.2, 7.27, 7.64, 8.26, 8.45, 7.59, 8.15, 8.33, 
8.32, 7.79, 7.8, 7.63, 8.51, 7.36, 8.13, 8.13, 8.45, 8.74, 8.82, 
8.29, 8.63, 8.37, 9.12, 8.92, 9.02, 9.21, 8.96, 9.28, 9.63, 8.96, 
8.77, 9.61, 9.62, 9.95, 9.89, 10.14, 10.17, 10.54, 10.98, 10.11, 
9.95, 10.24, 10.22, 10.16, 10.24, 10.47, 10.62, 10.66), rcp85_tg_mean_p90 = c(7.35, 
7.39, 6.72, 6.63, 6.87, 6.74, 6.86, 7.1, 6.51, 6.28, 7.08, 7.07, 
7.02, 7.43, 5.94, 5.8, 6.8, 6.82, 6.71, 6.76, 6.86, 7.04, 5.92, 
7.09, 6.64, 6.24, 7.02, 7.06, 6.81, 7.68, 6.93, 6.97, 6.5, 6.36, 
6.81, 6.77, 7.41, 6.72, 6.72, 7.08, 6.69, 7.57, 7.55, 7.22, 7.15, 
7.5, 6.7, 7.73, 7.4, 7.12, 7.74, 7.14, 7.81, 8.07, 7.89, 8.08, 
7.94, 8.35, 7.9, 8.39, 7.48, 7.8, 8.21, 7.74, 8.17, 7.76, 8.12, 
8.91, 9.15, 8.36, 8.36, 8.27, 9.07, 8.74, 8.58, 8.42, 8.26, 8.75, 
9.46, 8.76, 8.95, 8.68, 8.82, 9.28, 9.72, 9.74, 8.92, 10.03, 
9.46, 10.36, 9.94, 9.95, 9.71, 9.6, 10.05, 9.62, 9.64, 9.43, 
10.39, 10.4, 10.24, 10.56, 10.91, 10.63, 10.46, 10.96, 10.59, 
11.08, 11.49, 11.49, 11.69, 11.43, 11.35, 12.22, 11.46, 11.88, 
11.75, 12, 12.06, 12.46, 12.33, 12.29, 11.79, 11.93, 11.81, 12.31, 
12.11, 11.97, 12.8, 12.41, 12.96, 12.87, 12.81, 12.79, 13.27, 
12.82, 12.97, 12.86, 13.02, 13.15, 13.28, 13.5, 13.55, 13.54, 
14.29, 14, 13.74, 14.52, 14.46, 14.91, 14.46, 7.26, 7.3, 6.65, 
6.54, 6.78, 6.66, 6.77, 7.01, 6.43, 6.19, 6.99, 6.97, 6.93, 7.34, 
5.84, 5.71, 6.73, 6.75, 6.63, 6.66, 6.77, 6.98, 5.83, 7.02, 6.55, 
6.14, 6.93, 6.98, 6.72, 7.59, 6.84, 6.88, 6.4, 6.25, 6.72, 6.68, 
7.32, 6.62, 6.62, 6.98, 6.6, 7.51, 7.47, 7.15, 7.07, 7.42, 6.6, 
7.64, 7.32, 7.02, 7.66, 7.04, 7.72, 7.98, 7.81, 7.99, 7.84, 8.25, 
7.81, 8.29, 7.39, 7.7, 8.13, 7.67, 8.07, 7.66, 8.03, 8.81, 9.07, 
8.28, 8.28, 8.18, 8.99, 8.66, 8.48, 8.33, 8.16, 8.68, 9.37, 8.66, 
8.87, 8.56, 8.74, 9.21, 9.63, 9.67, 8.82, 9.94, 9.35, 10.28, 
9.86, 9.86, 9.61, 9.5, 9.96, 9.53, 9.54, 9.34, 10.31, 10.31, 
10.16, 10.46, 10.83, 10.54, 10.38, 10.88, 10.51, 10.99, 11.4, 
11.4, 11.61, 11.34, 11.26, 12.14, 11.37, 11.79, 11.66, 11.92, 
11.98, 12.38, 12.24, 12.2, 11.7, 11.85, 11.72, 12.23, 12.03, 
11.87, 12.73)), row.names = c(NA, 280L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using `dplyr`. `group_by` for each period (here rounding down to the nearest 30 years) and the grid cell, and then we can use `summarize(across(...` to calculate the mean for those three values within each group.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(yr30 = floor(lubridate::year(time)/30)*30, lon, lat) %>%
  summarize(across(value1:value3, mean), .groups = "drop")


# A tibble: 4 × 6
   yr30   lon   lat value1 value2 value3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1  1950 -80.8  43.0   2.75    5.5   8.25
2  1950 -80.6  43.0   1       2     3   
3  1950 -79.9  44.3   2       4     6   
4  1950 -79.9  44.3   1       2     3
```

---

sample data used:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
        time = c("1950-01-01","1951-01-01","1952-01-01",
                 "1953-01-01","1954-01-01","1955-01-01","1956-01-01",
                 "1957-01-01","1958-01-01","1959-01-01","1960-01-01","1950-01-01",
                 "1951-01-01","1950-01-01","1951-01-01"),
         lon = c(-80.79,-80.79,-80.79,-80.79,-80.79,
                 -80.79,-80.79,-80.79,-80.79,-80.79,-80.79,-80.63,-80.79,
                 -79.88,-79.88),
         lat = c(42.96,42.96,42.96,42.96,42.96,42.96,
                 42.96,42.96,42.96,42.96,42.96,42.96,42.96,44.29,44.26),
      value1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
      value2 = c(2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L),
      value3 = c(3L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 3L, 6L, 9L, 12L, 15L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 6L)
) 
df1$time = as.Date(df1$time)
```